# Get link name and write it down in a div

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

i want to use the name from the link that was clicked to show in an div. I tried many things but nothing comes out. I also have a little script to show and hide a div that worked fine until I tried to make a script for the name.
Would someone please take a quick look.

```
//script for hiding and display div
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
}
function hideDiv() {
   document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="maintab">
    <div class="tab" onclick="showDiv()" ><a href="#">Template</a></div>
</div>
<div id="bestelknop">**Here the name must come**</div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
    <ul>
        <a href="http://pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv()" name="Pixelweb">pixelweb</a>
        <a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be/social" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv()" name="Social">social</a>
        <a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv()" name="Templates" >templates pixelweb</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to display the name van de current link in the div bestelknop.

I'm a newbee in javascript so please help me with this.

Regards,

Benny

Comment: To show an element, set *style.display* to "" (empty string) so that the element adopts its inherited or default value.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the current link to the function.

Take a look to my working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XfW3P/

```
<div class="maintab">
    <div class="tab" onclick="showDiv()" ><a href="#">Template</a></div>
</div>
<div id="bestelknop">**Here the name must come**</div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
    <ul>
        <a href="http://pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Pixelweb">pixelweb</a>
        <a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be/social" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Social">social</a>
        <a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Templates" >templates pixelweb</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
}
function hideDiv(link) {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('bestelknop').innerHTML = link.name;
}
```

Comment: Nice, had the same idea as me. +1

Comment: hi, thanx for reply but can it be that in wont work because not the whole page is loaded again only the iframe? also i have said it wrong and it most show up in tab but that could not be it.

Answer (score 2):

First, pass `this` into your `onclick="hideDiv(this)" in each link:

```
<a href="http://pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Pixelweb">pixelweb</a>
<a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be/social" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Social">social</a>
<a href="http://templates.pixelweb.be" target="iframe" onclick="hideDiv(this)" name="Templates" >templates pixelweb</a>
```

Then, make change your `hideDiv()` function:

```
function hideDiv(obj) {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('bestelknop').innerHTML = obj.name + " " + obj.href;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUVtA/

Comment: if i make the changes the hideDiv wont work annymore. i have made a mistake by typing that the output must show up in the div bestelknop. It most come in the div tab. but that can't be the problem for this.